# Separating items into 2 columns by class

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Essentially, I want a set of elements (could be a list, or divs as below) which could be arranged in any order, but that will automatically move into a specified column based on their class.
For example, my HTML may be:

```
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
<div class="left"></div>
```

Let's assume a background color on each class:

```
.left{ background:red }
.right{ background:blue }
```

And I would be hoping to achieve a layout the attached image (the elements will stretch to fit the height of their respective content):

[image: Image columns]

Obviously, if I simply float elements left or right, they will wrap inline with the previous element, regardless of the height of the "column" I want to float it into.

I thought about flexbox, and wondered if you could specify 2 columns and align each element either left or right, but I don't think it's possible to specify the justification of an individual item.

I'm coming to the conclusion that this isn't going to be possible, short of using javascript to sort items into columns dynamically (e.g. similar to a masonry algorithm), but I thought I'd ask the question here in case anyone has any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

The basic idea is to use the `order` property to move the "left" elements to the beginning and the "right" elements to the end. Then we add a `breaker` element coming in between, which is tall enough to force a break.

```css
.block { width: 200px; margin: 20px; }
.left { order: 1; background: pink; }
.right { order: 3; background: cyan; }
.container { display: flex; flex-direction: column; flex-wrap: wrap; height: 1000px; }
.breaker { order: 2; flex-basis: 100%; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left block">Now is the time for all good men.</div>
  <div class="right block">Ipsum lorem.</div>
  <div class="right block">ed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto</div>
  <div class="left block"> occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum</div>
  <div class="left block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
  <div class="breaker"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is very interesting, thank you! I've been having a play with this. The only drawback that I can see is that the container must have a height specified, which means you would need to know the height of the content beforehand, or calculate it with JS, is that right?

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this easily using jQuery.
Create two divs "left" and "right"
And then appendTo child divs/elements depending on their class

```
if ($( "#mydiv" ).hasClass( "left" )){
$("#mydiv").appendTo(".left-container");
}
```

Comment: Please do not suggest jQuery solutions to questions not tagged as such.

Comment: I know I can do this with javascript, but am hoping for a purely CSS solution thanks

Answer (score -1):

Use common Class name for all div and as per your requirement add left right class also

```
if( $('.parentDiv).hasClass('left') ) {
    $('.parentDiv).css("float", "left");             
} else {
    $('.parentDiv').css("float", "right");             
}
```

Comment: You're probably going to need to provide a snippet to show that this actually works.

Comment: I don't think this works, plus it's using javascript. But also, that js seems unnecessary - you're just telling items with a class of left to float left. Why not just do that in pure CSS?